# Spying on a Javascript constructor using Jasmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm writing specs for some Javascript classes (backbone.js views, written in Coffeescript) and I'd like to ensure that one view constructs another.

I'm attempting to do this by spying on the constructor, like so:

```
describe 'Avia.AviaView', ->

  beforeEach ->
    @aviaView = new Avia.AviaView()
    @matricesView = new Backbone.View()
    spyOn(Avia.MatricesView, 'constructor').andReturn @matricesView

  describe 'initialize', ->

    beforeEach ->
      @aviaView.initialize()

    it 'creates a new MatricesView ', ->
      expect(Avia.MatricesView.constructor).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
```

The `initialize()` call on AviaView definitely causes the MatricesView constructor to be called, courtesy this line:

```
new Avia.MatricesView($("#tabs-3")).initialize()
```

It definitely works; if I run the app manually I can see the constructor being called during `initialize()`.  However my Jasmine spec fails:

```
Running Jasmine specs...
F

Avia.AviaView initialize creates a new MatricesView . (/Users/dev/avia/spec/javascripts/views/avia_view_spec.js.coffee:13)
  Expected constructor to be called exactly once, but was called '0' times (line ~14)
    expect(Avia.MatricesView.constructor).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();

FAIL: 1 test, 1 failure, 0.008 secs.
```

I've spoken to several of my colleagues, and they agree that this *should* work ... can anyone suggest a good way of spying on constructors?

Comment: From a first glance this seems like it has to do with scoping. How does the second beforeEach function have access to the first instance of [at]aviaView? Try changing beforeEach -> to beforeEach => so it will keep the parent scope. Also try defining [at]aviaView view just before [at]aviaView. CoffeeScript isn't like Ruby where the [at] automatically makes it an instance variable. SO isn't letting me type the at symbol.

Comment: Thanks - I tried moving everything into the same scope but the problem persists.  I'm pretty sure that the problem is I'm "doing it wrong" when it comes to spying on the constructor ... but I don't know what the right way _is_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
describe 'Avia.AviaView', ->

  beforeEach ->
    @aviaView = new Avia.AviaView()
    @matricesView = new Backbone.View()
    spyOn(Avia, 'MatricesView').andReturn @matricesView

  describe 'initialize', ->

    beforeEach ->
      @aviaView.initialize()

    it 'creates a new MatricesView ', ->
      expect(Avia.MatricesView).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
```

Comment: What if I'm spying on a built-in object, like `Date`? `spyOn(Date,'constructor').andCallThrough(); var d=new Date(); expect(Date.constructor).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: If the JS runtime won't allow you to modify core objects/classes, you'll need to create a wrapper object and use that in the class you're testing. This is a common technique in static languages (where mocking / stubbing is harder).